# Is WebSphere server mandatory to enable sso in Domino domain?

Tags: single-sign-on, websphere, ibm-domino

I want to configure sso between domino servers . all the server are in the same domains.

i have created the "web sso configuration document" and made the necessary chnages in server document. after restarting the http task i'm not getting any error in console regarding  sso . but single sign on is not working in the domain as i wanted , and important thing is after configuring this setting I'm not even able to login to any of the browsers, again and again I'm getting the same login page after entering user name password .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Websphere is not required. Domino can use its own SSO (by using Domino LTPA keys).

Here's a simple guide:
http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/dominowiki.nsf/dx/Configuring_single_sign-on_with_an_LTPA_token_on_IBM_WebSphere_and_IBM_Lotus_Domino_platforms#Configuring+Lotus+Domino+

Some things to check:

- Is the hostname specified in the Web SSO config document correct? That usually explains why you are directed to the login page after logging in.
- Do you use Internet Sites (i.e. is "Load Internet configurations from Server\Internet Sites documents" set in the server document)? if so, you must create your Web SSO config document under Internet Sites (and not under All Server Documents).